# Can't get my custom template to work with my custom subclass

Tags: templates, silverstripe

I'm developing a subclass of DropdownField and I'm trying to couple it with a corresponding DrodownFieldData.ss template without a success.

- I flushed the cache repeatedly.
- I deleted the cache folder on my localhost (XAMPP)
- I moved the template around to various locations of my 'simple' theme: `/simple/templates`, `/simple/templates/forms`, `/simple/templates/Includes`
- As you can see, the template name does not have an underscore character which has been reported to cause problems

I'm calling it as in:

```
return $this->customise($properties)->renderWith('DropdownFieldData');
```

Do you have any other ideas that I could give a try?

---

This is the code. It's basically a copy of DropdownField, skimmed down to the Field method.

```
<?php
class DropdownFieldData extends DropdownField {

    public function Field($properties = array()) {
        $source = $this->getSource();
        $options = array();
        if($source) {
            // SQLMap needs this to add an empty value to the options
            if(is_object($source) && $this->emptyString) {
                $options[] = new ArrayData(array(
                    'Value' => '',
                    'Title' => $this->emptyString,
                ));
            }

            foreach($source as $value => $title) {
                $selected = false;
                if($value === '' && ($this->value === '' || $this->value === null)) {
                    $selected = true;
                } else {
                    // check against value, fallback to a type check comparison when !value
                    if($value) {
                        $selected = ($value == $this->value);
                    } else {
                        $selected = ($value === $this->value) || (((string) $value) === ((string) $this->value));
                    }

                    $this->isSelected = $selected;
                }

                $disabled = false;
                if(in_array($value, $this->disabledItems) && $title != $this->emptyString ){
                    $disabled = 'disabled';
                }

                $options[] = new ArrayData(array(
                    'Title' => $title,
                    'Value' => $value,
                    'Selected' => $selected,
                    'Disabled' => $disabled,
                ));
            }
        }

        $properties = array_merge($properties, array('Options' => new ArrayList($options)));
        return $this->customise($properties)->renderWith('DropdownFieldData');

//      return parent::Field($properties);

    }
}
```

Comment: have you verified that `$this->customise($properties)->renderWith('DropdownFieldData');` even gets executed? perhaps you have put it at the wrong place? could you share your full class?

Comment: I edited my post to include the class code. The symptom remains.

Comment: Whoever downvoted my question, may they have the courage to explain why.

Comment: haha, obviously he/she had not. I see he/she removed the downvote again :D

Comment: about your problem, I will try your code on a local test environment sometime today. could you also include the template code that you are using and the filename you used?

Comment: Thanks Zauberfisch, you are being very helpful. As per the template: please do what I did: just clone `DropdownField.ss` to `DropdownFieldData.ss` and see if it works. As per the down/upvoting. The question had been upvoted and the downvoted, that's why it is zero now. I don't care about the reputation, I am just curious what the downvoter found wrong about my question.

Comment: might be tomorrow, haven't found time for it today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem that was the result of timing (there was a template loaded later that replaced my own customisation, but only when using the default form template). The fix was making sure the subclassed form field had its own version of the FormField Holder method. EG:

```
public function FieldHolder($properties = array()) {
    $obj = $properties ? $this->customise($properties) : $this;
    return $obj->renderWith($this->getTemplates());
}
```

The template should be in templates/forms/CustomField.ss. I don't think it should matter if this is in your theme folder, in mysite, or in a module folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

- rename your template DropdownFieldData_holder.ss
- move DropdownFieldData_holder.ss into mysite/templates/DropdownFieldData_holder.ss
- use the setFieldHolderTemplate method on your field, ie $this->setFieldHolderTemplate('DropdownFieldData_holder');

You'll also find that the fields are rendered using two templates, one of them being suffixed with '_holder', which acts as a wrapper, while the other one renders the field itself, so depending on how you want to customise your field, you might have to create both.

Have a look at the FormField class to get a better understanding on how fields are rendered, as they use a slightly different mechanism than page types

Comment: Thank, it did not help though. I'm trying to extend the Dropdown so that its `<option>`s have `data-*` attributes from specified columns of DataObject. Thus, I would want to only mess with the control itself, not its holder.

Answer (score 0):

The key was to keep the template in `[yourmodule]/templates`, rather than in any theme's location.